# Calculate monthly totals using php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I am using the following code to work out the totals for jobs that I have been doing. What I would like to do now is add a total for each month, but im not sure how to adapt it it do that. I need something like

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT SUM(pricequoted) pricequotedtotal,SUM(partprice) partpricetotal,SUM(profit) profittotal FROM `jobdetails` WHERE jobstatus='complete' AND WHERE `completeddate` = ALL DATES IN JANUARY, FEB, ETC ETC"
```

and do that for each month, so I can have for each month :
**January**
Quoted :
£200
Part Price :
£50
Profit :
£150

```
    // Work Complete Totals
    $query = $db->query("SELECT SUM(pricequoted) pricequotedtotal,SUM(partprice) partpricetotal,SUM(profit) profittotal FROM `jobdetails` WHERE jobstatus='complete'");
    $result = $query->fetch_object();
    $pricequoted1 = "{$result->pricequotedtotal}";
    $pricequoted = number_format($pricequoted1, 2, '.', '');
    $partprice1 = "{$result->partpricetotal}";
    $partprice = number_format($partprice1, 2, '.', '');
    $profit1 = "{$result->profittotal}";
    $profit = number_format($profit1, 2, '.', '');
    echo '<div style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">';
    echo '<strong>Work Complete Totals</strong>';
    echo '<p><strong style="color:red;">Quoted Total : &pound;'.$pricequoted.'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p><strong style="color:Darkorange ;">Parts Total : &pound;'.$partprice.'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p><strong style="color:green;">Profit Total : &pound;'.$profit.'</strong></p>';
    echo '</div>';
```

id
customerID
name
facebookuserurl
tel
email
address
itemforrepair
repairdetails
otherdetails
pricequoted
partprice
profit
datepartordered
jobstatus 
dateofcompletion
datecreated
itemnumber

47
bf0b4
Becki Lett
https://www.facebook.com/becki.lett
Laptop
My daughters laptop seems to have a prob and I wou...
Ok no problem, I should be able to fit you in towa...
0
1970-01-01
inprogressjobstodo
1970-01-01
2013-04-30
4558547578

Comment: You need to group your results by the approprate columns. Can you show us the schema of your table and a couple of sample rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly cleaned version of your code with the missing GROUP BY statement. Try this one.

```
// Work Complete Totals
$query = $db->query("SELECT SUM(pricequoted) AS pricequotedtotal,
                            SUM(partprice) AS partpricetotal,
                            SUM(profit) profittotal,
                            DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', completeddate) AS month 
                     FROM `jobdetails` 
                     WHERE jobstatus='complete'
                     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', completeddate)");


echo '<div style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">';
echo '<strong>Work Complete Totals</strong>';

while($result = $query->fetch_object()) {

    $pricequoted = number_format($result->pricequotedtotal, 2, '.', '');
    $partprice   = number_format($result->partpricetotal, 2, '.', '');
    $profit      = number_format($result->profittotal, 2, '.', '');

    echo '<p><strong style="color:red;">Quoted Total : &pound;'.$pricequoted.'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p><strong style="color:Darkorange ;">Parts Total : &pound;'.$partprice.'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p><strong style="color:green;">Profit Total : &pound;'.$profit.'</strong></p>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: has been added...
Choose either my version with year and month in one column or allen213 in two columns as you need.

Comment: Hi, this only seems to give me my totals so far still, but nothing more ?.

Comment: Ok, I dont think I know what you need then. You might just need to change the WHERE clause to something else. Maybe explain a bit more on what you want as result and whyt your schema is?

Comment: Damn, I forgot that you now have multiple rows ... Try now. (Blind coded and not executed though) ;)

Comment: by the way completeddate should be dateofcompletion but I changed that when I copied it anyway :-)

Comment: +1 from me for the general right answer and helping the OP through it

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql GROUP BY

eg

```
SELECT Year(record_date),MONTH(record_date),SUM(pricequoted) pricequotedtotal,SUM(partprice) partpricetotal,SUM(profit) profittotal FROM `jobdetails` 
WHERE jobstatus='complete'
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```

record_date would be a column of type date or datetime